# What's with the explosion in episode 18?

Tags: ghost-in-the-shell-sac

In SAC episode 18, we see Kusanagi stop Yu from physically attacking the Chinese foreign minister, but after her short exchange with Batou (who is standing nearby), Yu turns to smile and creates an explosion via some sort of detonation device in the bouquet he's carrying. From a bird's eye shot, we then see a somewhat large explosion.

Yet after that, we learn that the Chinese minister returned safely to China, and it looks like Kusanagi, Yu, and Batou are still alive.

What's with this explosion then, and why is no one (or at least the major, non-background characters) hurt? Somehow, the fact that Kusanagi is a cyborg doesn't quite seem to explain things, since this still doesn't deal with the other characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the very next scene, major Kusanagi explains:

> The risks, of course, are considerable, but we couldn't find a better solution than to further edit Yu's memories with a successful assassination attempt.

So what we see after the moment major attached a cyberbrain-disabling device to the back of his neck, is only a fake memory.

Comment: Hmmm, that struck me as a probable explanation, but it was hard for me to tell whether or not there was actually a "split" between the disabling of Yu's attack and the explosion (or well, if/when the major attached the device).